# Adding a marking to CGRect that is in Path block in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, border, swift5

I am trying to make a rectangle that is made of little squares in it. I am able to create the rectangle using the code given but I want to add a marking on the squares. This way the user can make a distinction between each and every square. I want it to look like a grid.

```
func drawBoard(boundingRect: CGSize) -> some View {
        let columns = self.numColumns
        let rows = self.numRows
        let blocksize = min(boundingRect.width/CGFloat(columns), boundingRect.height/CGFloat(rows))
        let xoffset = (boundingRect.width - blocksize*CGFloat(columns))/2
        let yoffset = (boundingRect.height - blocksize*CGFloat(rows))/2
        let gameBoard = self.gameBoard

        return ForEach(0...columns-1, id:\.self) { (column:Int) in
            ForEach(0...rows-1, id:\.self) { (row:Int) in
                Path { path in
                    let x = xoffset + blocksize * CGFloat(column)
                    let y = boundingRect.height - yoffset - blocksize*CGFloat(row+1)

                    let rect = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: blocksize, height: blocksize)
                    path.addRect(rect)
                }
                .fill(gameBoard[column][row].color)

            }
        }
    }
```

I am willing to change the entire code. I just need to make a grid...

[GRID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdcOQ.png)

Something like this or with borders or anything. Please help with this solution.

Comment: How does the code you posted fail to meet your needs? (And how are you using it? Are you calling it from `draw(_:)` for a view?

Comment: The code creates a rectangular block successfully but there are no markings between the squares. SO since the gameboard color is black you see a huge rectangle made with black colored squares but without any distinction between each. ```GeometryReader { (geometry: GeometryProxy) in
            self.drawBoard(boundingRect: geometry.size)
        }``` I am using this code to call the function. I basically need some space between each square or marking to create the distinction between each of the squares without losing the shape of rectangle.

Comment: Edit your question to explain that. People who are trying to help you should not have to sift through a bunch of comments to get the full picture. And what does `GeometryReader { (geometry: GeometryProxy) in self.drawBoard(boundingRect: geometry.size) }` mean? WE don't know anything about `GeometryReader` or `GeometryProxy`. Explain **in your question** in terms of view drawing cycle

Comment: When you post a question, step back from it. Think about somebody who's never seen your project, and knows nothing about what you're trying to do. Have you provided enough background for your readers to understand the problem you are trying to solve? If not, go back and **edit your question** to provide that background.